# jQuery image swap and animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a simple image swap, but when I add in my code for the swap, it doesn't work! I have a function toggling different classes which are animated using CSS which work fine without the image swap code, but once I add it in all of it breaks!

Could someone troubleshoot my code really quickly? I feel like my JQuery logic is a bit off.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var toggle = 0;

var toggleClass = function () {
    toggle = !toggle;
    $(".two").toggleClass("two-menu", toggle);
    $(".four").toggleClass("four-menu", toggle);
    $(".images").toggleClass("images-menu", toggle);
    $(".home").toggleClass("home-menu", toggle);

    $("#bottom-left").toggleClass("bottom-left", !toggle);
    $("#bottom-right").toggleClass("bottom-right", !toggle);
    $("#margin-zero").toggleClass("margin-zero", !toggle);

    $(".left-container").toggleClass("left-container-show", toggle);
    $(".right-container").toggleClass("right-container-show", toggle);
}

var imageSwap = function () {   
      this.src = '/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Twitter.jpg';
    }, function () {
  this.src = '/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Facebook.jpg';
}

jQuery(".home").click(function () {

    toggleClass();

});

jQuery(".two").click(function () {

    toggleClass();
    imageSwap();    

});

jQuery(".four").click(function () {
    toggleClass();

});

});
```

I've created two JSFiddles.

1) The first does not work, and includes the `imageSwap` function. http://jsfiddle.net/MuQ2w/

2) The second does not have the `imageSwap`, and works perfectly. http://jsfiddle.net/E2Rzv/

Comment: please post a jsfiddle for this code

Comment: Done. http://jsfiddle.net/MuQ2w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because of the syntax of you jQuery imageSwap function, as you can't write two function seperated with a "comma".
I think a possible solution might be to remove the second function.
Also imageSwap function doesnot know about 'this' as it is out of it's scope. You'll need to pass 'this' as an argument to it.
So the final imageSwap function will look like:

```
var imageSwap = function ($this) {  
    $this.src = '/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Facebook.jpg';
}
```

And your call to this function would be like:

```
jQuery(".two").click(function () {
    imageSwap(this);    
    toggleClass();
});
```

I hope it will help.

P.S. Just to follow the tradition, here is a working fiddle:
[jsfiddle.net/gKxLz](http://jsfiddle.net/gKxLz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

did you look in your console for the errors? `

```
var imageSwap = function () {   
      this.src = '/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Twitter.jpg';
    }, function () {
  this.src = '/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Facebook.jpg';
}
```

is not correct syntax: the second function has no variable name

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to figure out what is happening without debugging the code.

I am guessing that perhaps the problem is due to the scope of "this" inside imageSwap function.

Try to pass this (for the handler) to imageSwap function as a parameter, like:

```
var imageSwap = function ($this) {   
    $this.src = '/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Twitter.jpg';
    }, function ($this) {
    $this.src = '/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Facebook.jpg';
}

jQuery(".two").click(function () {
    toggleClass();
    imageSwap(this, this);    

});
```

Hope it will work